# Problem with showing the activity of Paint in ANDROID

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-canvas

to everyone, I tried to Create a paint ACTIVITY in the android but it shows the error in opening the painting activity. I don't know what is the proper way to resolve this problem. I hope the community of this stack overflow will help me to resolve this problem. Thanks

Please help me with that so that I can create a painting activity in ANDROID

**activity_paint.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activity_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    tools:context=".PaintActivity">


    <com.app.drawing.Util.CanvasView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </com.app.drawing.Util.CanvasView>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/start_new"
            android:src="@drawable/new_pic" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/brush"
            android:src="@drawable/brush" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/erase_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/erase"
            android:src="@drawable/eraser" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/save_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/save"
            android:src="@drawable/save" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <!-- Top Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/paint_colors"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF660000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF660000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF0000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF6600"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF6600" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFCC00"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFFCC00" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF009900"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF009900" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF009999"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF009999" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF0000FF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF990099"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF990099" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF6666"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF6666" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF787878"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF787878" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**PaintActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.learnbest_kidsapp;
    
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    public class PaintActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{
    
        private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn,baru,erase,save;
        private DrawingView drawView;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_paint);
    
    //=======================this is the 31 line========================================
            drawView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
            //=======================this is the 31 line========================================
            drawBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
            baru = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_btn);
            erase = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.erase_btn);
            save = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
            LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
            currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
            currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
            drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            baru.setOnClickListener(this);
            erase.setOnClickListener(this);
            save.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public void paintClicked(View view){
            if(view!=currPaint){
                ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
                String color = view.getTag().toString();
                drawView.setColor(color);
                imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
                currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
                currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
    
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId()==R.id.draw_btn){
                drawView.setupDrawing();
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.erase_btn){
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.new_btn){
                AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
                newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
                newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        drawView.startNew();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                newDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                newDialog.show();
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
                AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
                saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
                saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                                getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                                UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
                        if(imgSaved!=null){
                            Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            savedToast.show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            unsavedToast.show();
                        }
                        drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
    
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.show();
            }
    
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

**Error**

```
     D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.example.learnbest_kidsapp, PID: 19987
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.learnbest_kidsapp/com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.PaintActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.DrawingView
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.DrawingView
                at com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.PaintActivity.onCreate(PaintActivity.java:31)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19987 SIG: 9
        Process 19987 terminated.
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: thanks for your response @DanBaruch  the error I got is       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.learnbest_kidsapp/com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.PaintActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.DrawingView

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.DrawingView
                at com.example.learnbest_kidsapp.PaintActivity.onCreate(PaintActivity.java:31)

Comment: Well, it tells your quite straight forward. your object called "drawView" of type DrawingView can not be used to point to your view drawing as it can not cast it from AppBarLayout to DrawingView. Change the drawView type to AppBarLayout

Comment: Change
private DrawingView drawView;
to
private AppBarLayout drawView;

Comment: well thanks, I changed the drawView type to AppBarLayout. But after that, it gave me some of the errors in the methods I used in it. Which are                                                          drawView.setColor(color);                                     
drawView.setupDrawing();
drawView.setErase(true);
drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());      drawView.startNew();

Comment: Well, then there's some misunderstanding here, you are using a View from one type (AppBarLayout) but applying all the functions on a different type of View. You have to either read how to apply what you want to do to AppBarLayout view or replace AppBarLayout with DrawingView in the XML file.

Comment: @DanBaruch, for your such a great help. Actually, I need to select the different colors and want to paint on the canvas, also want to erase save undo-redo the paint steps. Could you please provide the code for that so that I can do complete my project thanks

Comment: Well, I'd help with that but I haven't used DrawingView or AppBarLayout. In general though, you can create a Paint object with specific color (Paint p = new Paint(); p.setColor(Color.X);) and type of drawing (p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)). and to draw you just call Canvas.drawOval/Rect/Line/Path and so on. To undo and redo, you basically use a stack to save any changes made on the canvas and when the user undo/redo you just pop the stack to perform the action (since you want both redo and undo I'd use 2 stacks)